# Independent System Time for VB.NET or MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datetime

I've been searching the web for any search result of making a datetime that is not dependent in the computer's date and time. I am creating a system that requires a datetime to be saved in Mysql DB with VB.net, and i noticed that once i change the datetime of my computer the datetime.now.tostring of vb.net changes to so the transactions i save in mysql db can be compromised.

my question is how will I implement a DATETIME that is not dependent on the computer's DATETIME.

Comment: you could poll an internet time server in your region to get the time.

Comment: using NTP server? what if the computer has no internet connection?

Comment: How are you using vb.net-2010 and vb6?

Comment: im using a vb.net(i dont know what year) in VS 2015

Comment: i'm a little confused. Do you mean that when you insert or update a record in MySql you want to record a timestamp in a table field?

Comment: if your system is depending on an accurate, system-independent time for some reason, then you'll need an internet connection,  By the way, doing `DateTime.Now.ToString()` results in a string, not a `DateTime` var

Comment: @SamM yes. but that is not dependent in the computer's datetime.

Comment: @Plutonix yess yess sorry. i actually using a custom format for that DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm:ss")

Comment: what im i trying to solve is to prevent an intruder to change the TRUE datetime to manipulate the transactions made in my system

Comment: If you're not able to depend on an outside source (such as an NTP server) for the date value, what other choice do you have but the computer time? Where would this magic datetime value originate? You have two choices: the computer clock, or an external source. Take your pick - there is no magical third option except to invent a time system yourself. Make up your mind: do you want an *independent source* (which would rely on access to that source) or not?

Comment: @kenWhite but it is possible to use both options? and how would i communicate with the NTP server? is thers a documentation for using NTP?

Comment: Google can answer that question; but of course. NTP is a network time protocol (which is what NTP stands for), and there is documentation for it. You communicate with an NTP server via an internet connection, of course. Outside of a modem or disk/thumb drive, it's the only way to get information between the computer and the world around it.

Comment: A quick search of this site for `ntp .net` turned up quite a few links that would be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your update or insert statement, use the MySql `now()` function. It will timestamp based on the database server's time. For example:

```
UPDATE my_table
   SET field1 = :somevalue,
       field2 = :anothervalue,
       field3timestamp = Now()
 WHERE identifier = :whatever;
```

Comment: is MySQL timestamp dependent to computers datetime?

Comment: It is based on the server's datetime. Is the database on your computer or on a server?

Comment: on computer. Im creating a Sales Inventory System and im preventing user to manipulate time so that transactions will not be compromise.

Comment: So when you deploy your product it will be talking to a database on the user's computer? If so, NTP is the only way to go and as others have stated above, you will need an internet connection for that. But if the production database is on a server, use my answer.